# Keep displaying current org heading info in some way

Tags: org-mode

Often I have a problem that I browse through the content of the heading but I forget what is a heading I'm currently at. So I leave the mark, go back to the heading, read it, and jump back to the mark. It disrupts the workflow and wastes time.

I think the solution to this problem would be displaying the current heading (or entire heading path separated by "/" or similar) in the echo area while I browse/edit heading content or make it stick to the top in a similar way `position: sticky` in CSS3 works.

Are there any plugins or configuration options that address this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add something to either the [mode line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html#Mode-Line-Format) or the [header line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Header-Lines.html#Header-Lines) to keep track of such things. Here I use the header line because the mode line is usually rather crowded, whereas the header line is not used as frequently.

You can add a header line to any buffer by

```
(setq header-line-format "foo")
```

That makes `header-line-format` a buffer-local variable with the value `foo` which is displayed at the top of the buffer window. Whenever the value of `header-line-format` changes, the buffer is marked for redisplay, so you always see the currently set value.

You can have the header line dynamically change by doing this:

```
(setq header-line-format '(:eval FORM))
```

The form is evaluated [whenever emacs thinks that it should be](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Basics.html#Mode-Line-Basics) - but you can force the re-evaluation if needed - my experiments show that it is not needed: emacs does the right thing on its own.

So all we have to do for this particular case is write a function `ndk/org-breadcrumbs` that calculates what you want to show and do

```
(setq header-line-format '(:eval (ndk/org-breadcrumbs)))
```

The function is modeled after a [similar calculation](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/org-agenda.el#L6688) that is done in the agenda for the `%b` specification in `org-agenda-prefix` where the name `breadcrumbs` is used to indicate the chain of headings that get you to the current heading.

```
(defun ndk/heading-title ()
   "Get the heading title."
   (save-excursion
     (if (not (org-at-heading-p))
       (org-previous-visible-heading 1))
     (org-element-property :title (org-element-at-point))))

(defun ndk/org-breadcrumbs ()
   "Get the chain of headings from the top level down
    to the current heading."
   (let ((breadcrumbs (org-format-outline-path
                         (org-get-outline-path)
                         (1- (frame-width))
                         nil "->"))
         (title (ndk/heading-title)))
     (if (string-empty-p breadcrumbs)
         title
       (format "%s->%s" breadcrumbs title))))

(setq header-line-format '(:eval (ndk/org-breadcrumbs)))
```

If you just want the title of the containing section, you can just use `ndk/heading-title`:

```
(setq header-line-format '(:eval (ndk/heading-title)))
```

but the extended `breadcrumbs` version seems attractive to me.

Setting the `header-line-format` variable can be done for a single buffer as above, or if you want this for *every* Org mode buffer it can be done in the mode hook:

```
(defun ndk/set-header-line-format()
  (setq header-line-format '(:eval (ndk/org-breadcrumbs))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'ndk/set-header-line-format)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect.

Comment: Great! Glad you liked it :-)